# Passing a list of generic parameters with different types in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible in C# but maybe someone can guide me into the right direction.

I'm trying to create a generic function that executes different SQL Stored Procs. I want to pass i name of the procedure, parameters and a callback function to fire after the connection is made.
But the problem I encountered is that I cannot pas a generic array of parameters of various types. Altho SQLParam is also a generic class I have to specify it's type in ExecuteSQL() function which limits the types of all params to just one type.

Is there a way to get around this limitation somehow?

```
public static class SQL<T> {
    async public static Task<T> ExecuteSQL(string ProcName, List<SQLParam<...ONE TYPE...>> Params, Func<SqlCommand, T> callback)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Utilities.Common.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection")))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(ProcName) { CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, Connection = sqlConnection })
            {
                Params.ForEach(param => sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + param.Name, param.Value)));


                sqlConnection.Open();

                return callback(sqlCommand);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SQLParam<T> { 
    string Name { get; set; }
    T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do not use a generic type, use `object` (`System.Object`) instead. That is also the type of `Value` property of a `DbParameter` instance and the inherited types like `SqlParameter`. I would make this a little simpler though, have your code take a list of SqlParameter types instead of a list of Objects. Then pass that list directly to the command. This would allow for more flexibility like also specifying the db type, the length, and setting a DBNull.Value when applicable.

Comment: It begs the question why you need this class when you already have `SqlParameter`?